# Creating a particle with gaussian distribution of light intensity

Tags: python, image-processing, spyder, particles

I am trying to model a particle of radius x , for the purpose of PIV(particle image velocimetry). I would like to have a gaussian distribution of the light intensity from the center and radiating outwards. It will be great if I can get some links, resources, advices that could be helpful.

PS: I am no programmer, just a fluid mechanics enthusiastic.

[I would like to create a particle like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQGsf.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far? We can only answer specific programming questions here. Please see [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: are you asking how to generate an array of values that represents a 2d gaussian distribution?